# React-Native How can I modify an object in an array using a filter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

I made the above arrangement using `useState`.

I created a function to add `{value: "", key: ""}` to the `items` array.

I want `title` of `arr0` to change according to `items.key`.

I used the `filter` thinking `key == 0` but it didn't work.

```
return (
 <View>
   arr0={[
           {
             title: items.filter((data) => (data.key == 0 ? "A" 
  : "B")),
           
        ]}
 </View>
)
```

If you have a good opinion, please give me some advice. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Remove brackets around the return value

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the answer you said seems to be a misunderstanding that I wrote the wrong function. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using length instead of filter. It's a simple example, but I'm leaving an answer just in case there's someone wandering around like me!

```
title: items.filter((data) => (data.key == 0).length < 1 ? "a" : "b")
```